# cannot connect with Cloud SQL Proxy without Elevated privileges

Tags: security, proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We are attempting to configure Dev users at a project level with only 'viewer' access and also allow them to login to Cloud SQL. Strangely there are no granular permissions as there are for DataStore or Bigquery.

When attempting to connect after configuring the Cloud SQL proxy to follow Google best practice for connecting to V2 Cloud SQL instances.

The connection is refused in MySQL workbench and the following message appears in the Proxy window.

[image]

As soon as the Project privileges are changed to 'editor' in IAM, the same connection works fine. With a lack of roles for Cloud SQL, this means all users either cant access Cloud SQL v2 with proxy or can reset the root password.

Hopefully we are mistaken as this seems like a serious security issue?

Comment: Please send an e-mail to cloud-sql@google.com and reference this thread and I can provide some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, at this time the actor must have at least 'project editor' role to connect using the Cloud SQL Proxy.